# LotusNotes: db.GetView() returns nothing

Tags: lotus-notes, lotus-domino, lotusscript, lotus, lotus-formula

I have a view called "mpending". I am trying to get the view in an agent.
Here is the code snippet of how I am doing it:

```
Dim db As NotesDatabase
Set db = New NotesDatabase("","app.nsf")
Dim view As NotesView
Set view = db.GetView("mpending")
```

Then the view is assigned with nothing.

I am quite new to LotusNotes. Am I doing the right thing?

Comment: I found this is happening to newly created view.  Is there anything that I need to do to include newly created view. Like kind of refresh or  update ?

Comment: How, exactly, are you testing this code? Are you running it locally in Domino Designer on your desktop/laptop machine? Is the "app.nsf" database file located on the same machine that the agent is running on? Did you add the view in the "app.nsf" database file on that machine?

Comment: I am running it locally in Notes Client. In the Designer I wrote the agent. Then I open up Notes Client to execute the agent. The "app.nsf" datebase file is located on the same machine, on a Windows Server.  What do you mean by adding the view in the file on that machine?

Comment: I tried to use db.Views() and found the view I created is not in that list. I am guessing I could see the view in the Notes Client but still somehow it is not in the database yet.

Comment: Did you create the view in designer or as a private view in the client?

Comment: Yep. I create the view in designer. Do you know how to make it not private or how to get a private view in an agent?

Comment: And when I created the view, in the type I actually already select Shared instead of Private.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am really not a Lotus Notes Developer. 
Finally the problem has been resolved for my own case, but it might not be the usual case.
I got this Lotus Notes Export job because I am developing a Google App Engine app to replace an old Lotus Notes App and has to migrate the old data.

What I did:
I open up the Notes Designer and add some views. Then I want to export them to a csv file.
It turns out that the way I construct the database is not right.

```
Dim db As NotesDatabase
Set db = New NotesDatabase("","app.nsf")
```

This way, db cannot find the view I recently created.

```
Dim db As NotesDatabase
Dim ss As New NotesSession
Set db = ss.Currentdatabase
```

This one, I could get the view I just created.

I think the reason behind might be that one is looking at local the other is looking at production. The production don't have the changes I made after a certain point.

Comment: Aha. This is one of the possibilities that I was trying to get at with my questions to you. I think you must have the Notes client, Domino Designer, and the Domino server all installed on one machine. This means that you have two data directories: e.g., IBM\Lotus\Notes\Data and IBM\Lotus\Domino\Data. When you are running code in the Domino Designer, the "" that you use in the first argument for new NotesDatabase refers to IBM\Lotus\Notes\Data\app.nsf, but your app.nsf is really in IBM\Lotus\Domino\Data.app.nsf. That copy is what you have opened in Designer, so that is the CurrentDatabase.

Comment: Why is has two locations for the same database?  Are both of them useful?

Comment: When you create a database, you have the choice between saving the NSF file on "Local" (or "On my computer") which will put it in the IBM\Lotus\Notes\Data folder on your machine, or you can select the name of a Domino server and it will be saved in that server's IBM\Lotus\Domino\Data folder. If the client and the server software are installed on the same machine, both folders will exist and you have to be careful to make sure that you (and your code) are consistently choosing the correct location.

Answer (score 0):

Private views in the desktop are not returned with db. getview("")

http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSVRGU_9.0.1/com.ibm.designer.domino.main.doc/H_GETVIEW_METHOD.html

Comment: Do you know if there is a way to get a private view in an agent code? Or if there is no way to do so, how to make it not private?

Comment: I checked the type for my view. I set it as Shared. So I guess it is not a private view?    Do I need to publish it or something to make it available by db.getview("")?

Comment: If the view is shared you'll get it with db.getView(""). Is your local Database in the Notes Data Directory?

Comment: What do you mean by Notes Data Directory? app.nsf file is located E:\Program Files\IBM\Lotus\Notes\Data. I think it is in Notes Data Directory.   I created several views by the default view type( shared). All of them cannot be accessed by .GetView() method.   I created the view in this way. I remote connect to a windows server, open up Notes Designer, create a new view, then I open up the Notes Client I could see the newly created view. But not by using GetView(). Is this something related to Refresh Design Or Publish the views?

Answer (score 0):

In one of your comments you say "The app.nsf datebase file is located on the same machine, on a Windows Server".

The code points to app.nsf located locally, in your Notes Data directory. Unless you specify a path in the second argument to the New NotesDatabase constructor, that is where it will look.

Don't put databases on a file server on the network if you access them as local databases. Either keep them in the Notes Data directory (or in a directory below), or use an actual DOmino server for the databases.